How to render image in the 'getOptionLabel' in Autocomplete material UI component?
Not able to render the image inside the 'getOptionLabel' in Autocomplete tag React.
I tried adding the  tag inside the 'getOptionLabel', but getting it as [object object].
I can able to display data in strings , but the img tag is not displaying the image in the textfiled, instead printing it as [object object].


Can add some code you are trying
